# How can i edit in settings.json the configuration of the "Debug Python File" button in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

So I was trying to debug a python code when an error popped up saying `[Errno 2] No such file or directory:`, but the file was in the project, but it was in a separate folder next to the python file. I realised after some searching that the python file was running in the folder that was opened in vscode.

[image]

[image]

I tried to change the configuration of the debugger in the `settings.json` file and now I have a debugger that works as I wish, but I would like to access my debugging configuration through the Run and Debug button

[image]

My `settings.json` file

[image]

Comment: use `F5` and launch configs, **DON'T** use that button in the top right, nobody knows what that button does, and don't use `code-runner`, read the VSC Python doc pages

Answer (score 0):

You can use debug as shown in the following figure:

1. Click **Run and Debug** on the left menu.
2. Click `start debugging` button which is the same as shortcuts **F5** sa rioV8 said.

[image]

Comment: I understand that I can use the Run and Debug menu but is more comfortable to use that big button in the corner of the screen and I'm just wondering how can i change it's configuration

Comment: @marc.mitrasca That's called **Basic debugging**. The settings in your `launch.json` will not work. For some simple scripts, you can use that button.